# Kohana 2.x restoring session

Tags: php, session, kohana

Is there a way to restore session, knowing its ID, in Kohana 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Kohana 2.* repository: [Line 113 of system/libraries/Session.php](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/kohana2/repository/entry/trunk/system/libraries/Session.php#L113). `Session::instance` allows for an ID to be passed in.

```
/**
 * Singleton instance of Session.
 *
 * ##### Example
 *
 *     // This is the idiomatic and preferred method of starting a session
 *     $session = Session::instance();
 *
 * @param string Force a specific session_id
 */
public static function instance($session_id = NULL)
{
    if (Session::$instance == NULL)
    {
        // Create a new instance
        new Session($session_id);
    }
    elseif( ! is_null($session_id) AND $session_id != session_id() )
    {
        throw new Kohana_Exception('A session (SID: :session:) is already open, cannot open the specified session (SID: :new_session:).', array(':session:' => session_id(), ':new_session:' => $session_id));
    }

    return Session::$instance;
}
```